# 404 error when making a POST call from Angular HttpClient to ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API (with CORS enabled)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I've written a simple `ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API`. The `POST` method always returns a `404`, but GET requests succeed.

```
public class TestPayload
{
    public string test1 { get; set; }
    public string test2 { get; set; }
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController: ControllerBase
{        
    // POST api/create
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Create([FromBody] TestPayload value)
    {
        return Ok("");
    }
}
```

I get back a 404 error in my Angular HttpClient front-end.

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

return this.http.post<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/test/create`, { test1, test2}, { headers }).pipe(map(x => {
                        ...               
                        return x;
                       }));
```

I get the same error in Postman.

```
POST /api/Test/Create HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5001
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 4d304e86-013c-4be8-af07-f2262079000d
{ test1: "val1", test2: "val2" }------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

I have enabled the most permissive CORS policies (to test with) in my Startup.cs file, but it doesn't fix the issue.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
            builder =>
            {
                builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
            });
    });
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);       
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseCors("AllowAll");
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

I see the following message in the Output window in Visual Studio, which leads me to believe it is a CORS error, but I don't know what I have done wrong. My breakpoints inside the method never get hit, even though symbols are loaded and they are hit in the GET methods.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel:Information: Connection id "0HLKU1LFDTCPA", Request id "0HLKU1LFDTCPA:00000002": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
```

This is running all on localhost. I have installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors (2.2.0) NuGet package in my project.

Comment: where is the TestPayload  class ? are you sure you are calling the method with correct post data ? seems like you are sending wrong data.

Comment: Based on the route attributes on the .net api controller, you are calling the wrong URL. So the not found error is accurate. You need to POST to `api/test` or change the route templates on the controller to match the intended URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not specified a route to the action. You can either change your post to go to /api/Test or set the attributes on the action as follows:

```
[HttpPost("Create")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Create([FromBody] TestPayload value)
{
    return Ok("");
}
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Create")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Create([FromBody] TestPayload value)
{
    return Ok("");
}
```

or update the controller route to include the action

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
[EnableCors(origins: " * ", headers: " * ", methods: " * ")]
```

to your Controller class. ( remove  with spaces in the quotes )

More info on [Microsoft-Website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: Can you explain why CORS rules would help? Normally an OPTIONS call would fail if CORS is wrong, rather than producing a 404 (NotFound).